# PushSharp: 'DeviceSubscriptionChanged', what should I do?

Tags: pushsharp

I'm using the PushSharp library
I'm handling this event right now: DeviceSubscriptionChanged

My question is if the notification has been sent to the new Token and the only thing I should do is to update the new token replacing the old one.
Or, on the other hand, I also should resend the notification to the new Token...

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, here someone gave me the answer

https://github.com/Redth/PushSharp/issues/468

The answer is that the only thing I should do when the event is trigger is just to replace the old token for the new one.

Hope this will help somebody!